# react-dom.development.js:14757 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {quan}). though quan is deleted

Tags: reactjs

I want to update delivery on click.So have done the code.but after this my whole react app crashed.it says react-dom.development.js:14757 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {quan}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
**Input:**

```
import React ,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import { useParams ,useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Card, Col, Row,Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
const InventoryItemDetail = () => {
    //const [quan,  setQuan]=useState();
    const [product,setProduct]=useState({});
    const {id}=useParams();
    const [itemDetail,setItemDetail]=useState([]);
    const navigate=useNavigate();
const manageInventoryRedirect=()=>{
    navigate('/manageInventory')
}

 const {_id,image,name,description,quantity,price,supplier}=itemDetail;

export default InventoryItemDetail;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are using  `{product}` `object` in the JSX , maybe you want to draw
`{ JSON.stringify(product) }` or **product.quantity** for example

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand.What i have to change?

Comment: it doesn't solved.even if i delete whole product.quantity,it doesn't help

Comment: see attached image

Comment: As I understand the problem is using Objects inside of JSX , try to find where you are using objects

Comment: Remove {product} that I mention image above, is it solved the problem?